# Should I need to refresh the page in order to get user data?

Tags: node.js, angular

Right now I have to refresh the page in order to get user data from local storage, I'm not sure that this is the correct way of doing things. How would I go about getting user data on login? Right now I'm just grabbing it from a local storage JWT but that doesn't seem like best practice. Should I be getting the user based on their ID every time they log in? How do I persist that data?

```
reload(){
    this.router.navigate(['/']);
  }

login(userName: string, email: string, password: string) {
    const authData: LoginData = {userName, email, password };
    console.log('AuthData', authData);
    this.http.post<{token: string, expiresIn: number, displayName: string}>(this.loginRoute, authData)
      .subscribe(response => {
        const token = response.token;
        this.token = token;
        if (token) {
          const expiresInDuration = response.expiresIn;
          this.setAuthTimer(expiresInDuration);
          this.isAuthenticated = true;
          this.username = response.displayName;
          this.authStatus.next(true);
          const now = new Date();
          const expirationDate = new Date(now.getTime() + expiresInDuration * 1000);
          console.log(expirationDate);
          this.saveAuthData(token, expirationDate, userName);
          this.reload();
        }
      });
  }
```

I'd like to be able to display the user data on my home page of the user that is currently logged in but am unsure how to persist that data. right now I'm just using local storage.

Comment: the user data should be persisted in the database alone. It is extremely dangerous to persist user data in the browser. You should only be persisting the token. You can keep the username in a shared service during the session. But every time the user logs in you need to make a new request

Comment: @sinanspd the only thing I'm storing in the local storage is username and userID

Comment: I wouldn't even store the plain id. You have to create a JWT token in the server, that denotes if the user is logged in. When the page is initialized you send that token to the server which resolves it to a user and sends it back

Comment: @sinanspd I have to store that token though in order to send it to the server, and it needs some details of the user or I wouldn't be able to log the user in.

Comment: that token should be encrypted is the point I am trying make. Again, to answer your question and comment below, you don't need to make a request to the server on every page load, you can do it once per session and store the details in a shared service

Answer (score 0):

Without a backend, you don't have a ton of options (like websockets). But with what you have you could create a separate function from login that checks if the user is actually authenticated and put it in an interval and poll it every X seconds. This will get rid of the reload function. You would create an Observable onInit that just goes off every 10 seconds or whatever and checks the status of the token.

Cheers!

Comment: I have a backend. I think my question wasn't worded very well.

Comment: Or maybe I didn't understand!

Comment: How do you know when the token has expired? Why exactly are you reloading after your login call?

Comment: So I'm expiring the token after an hour and when the token expires it logs the user out. However I just want access to user data so I can display it on the front end. In order to get that data right now I'm just using the local storage data but I probably need to do a call to the backend with the user ID I'm assuming. But do I do that on every page load?

Comment: Yes, if you don't want to use localstorage. You could do a simple `isUserLoggedIn()` check at the beginning of each backend call that just simply checks if the token is still valid. If it isn't, it fails/routes the user to login again.